# Self-join returns incorrect / opposite results?

Tags: php, codeigniter, self-join

I need to use Self Join below table, using Codeigniter.

```
+----------------------------+
| id | parent_id |  name     |
+----------------------------+
|  1 |  0        |  Ram      |
+----------------------------+
|  2 |  0        |  Alex     |
+----------------------------+ 
|  3 |  1        |  Sep      |
+----------------------------+ 
|  4 |  1        |  Mid      |
+----------------------------+ 
|  5 |  2        |  Seem     |
+----------------------------+
|  6 |  3        |  Julie    |
+----------------------------+
```

How to use the CodeIgniter query to get the output like below

```
+--------------------------------+
| id |  name     |  parent_name  |
+--------------------------------+
|  1 |  Ram      |     NULL      |
+--------------------------------+
|  2 |  Alex     |     NULL      |
+--------------------------------+
|  3 |  Sep      |     Ram       |
+--------------------------------+
|  4 |  Mid      |     Ram       |
+--------------------------------+
|  5 |  Seem     |     Alex      |
+--------------------------------+
|  6 |  Julie    |     Sep       |
+--------------------------------+
```

I have used the alias to select the data like below.

```
$this->db->select('p.id as p_id, p.name as p_name, p_parent.name as parent_name');
$this->db->from('Product as p');
$this->db->join('Product as p_parent', 'p_parent.parent_id = p.id   ','LEFT ');
$results = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

I am getting multiple arrays and not getting the right result.

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [p_id] => 1 [p_name] => ram [parent_name] => sep ) 
 [1] => Array ( [p_id] => 1 [p_name] => ram [parent_name] => Mid ) 
     . . . 
 [6] => Array ( [p_id] => 6 [p_name] => julie [parent_name] => ) )
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Well, does it produce the result that you want?

Comment: Can you get the appropriate result ?

Comment: @Patrick 
Nop. I am getting multiple arrays and not getting the right. result

Comment: can you please add your result here for better understanding ?

Comment: Reverse your ON condition

Comment: Can you also add your expected result in the question please ?

Comment: @Nick. It's already there in the question. Please check the second table.

Comment: Try `$this->db->group_by('p.id');`

Comment: @Patrick You got the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query to get the output as second table

```
$this->db->select('p.id as id, p.name as name, p_parent.name as parent_name');
$this->db->from('Product as p');
$this->db->join('Product as p_parent', 'p.parent_id = p_parent.id  ','left');
$results = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please approve my answer. :)

Comment: I have accepted your answer. But I can't upvote the answer since I didn't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: It's ok, Thanks. :)